# MySQL 5.5 UNIX_TIMESTAMP function returns different values on prod and local machines

Tags: mysql, docker, unix-timestamp

I have an old PHP system, using MySQL 5.5.47 as DB.

The guys who have created the system, have taken a strange decision.
In some cases, they saved a date value without day - for example '**2018-01-00**'. The field type is DATE.

A lot of queries use where clause like this: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(<DATE>)) BETWEEN 1514757600 AND 1546207210`, where `<DATE>` is a column which contains records like '2018-01-00', '2018-02-00', etc.
The two timestamps represent dates 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31.

On production, this type of queries run without issue.
On my local machine, they do not return any results.

What I found is if I run the command: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE( '2018-01-00' ) )` on production the result is **1514757600**, but on my local machine it returns **0**.

I'm using a Docker compose to reproduce the production as close as possible. Initially, I have used MySQL 5.6 for local development when I hit this issue, I tried with MySQL 5.5.62, but the result is same.

Does anyone know how I can set up my local MySQL to work as the production one?

---

Query on **production**:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE('2018-01-00'), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE('2018-01-00')), UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-00');
+--------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| DATE('2018-01-00') | UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE('2018-01-00')) | UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-00') |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| 2018-01-00         |                         1514757600 |                            0 |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Query on **local**:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE('2018-01-00'), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE('2018-01-00')), UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-00');
+--------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| DATE('2018-01-00') | UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE('2018-01-00')) | UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-00') |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| 2018-01-00         |                                  0 |                            0 |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you have the same settings in my.cnf?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a **bug** in Mysql prior 5.5.48. In the release notes of 5.5.48, there is a statement about fixing a bug related to the unix_timestamp function.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-48.html

> When an invalid date was supplied to the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function using the STR_TO_DATE() function, no check was performed before converting it to a timestamp value. (Bug #21564557)